# Interrupting foreach loop to add additional text

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to figure out how to place additional text at a specific point inside of a foreach loop, so the output of my php would be:

Alabama Alaska Arizona Arkansas **SomeNewText** 
California Colorado Connecticut etc etc etc

continue; and break; don't seem to work in this case. I **don't** want to stop/quit the foreach loop.

```
<?php

$items = array("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Dist of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming");


$count = 0;

foreach ($items as $item) 
{

if ($count == 3)
{
echo 'SomeNewText';
}

echo $item;
echo "\n";

$count++;

}

?>
```

Any ideas?  Thx.

Comment: your title and your text look like separate questions. Do you want to quit the foreach loop when count reaches 3 ?

Comment: You definitely don't want a **continue** there. Aaand yes, you need to close your foreach loop. Other than that, the code should do the job.

Comment: No, I don't want to quit the foreach loop: I want to inject additional text at some point within the loop.

Comment: The code does not work, as it outputs "SomeNewText" more than once: at the 4th, 10th, etc, positions:  Alabama  Alaska  Arizona  SomeNewText Arkansas  California
Colorado  Connecticut  Delaware  SomeNewText Dist of Columbia  Florida

Answer (score 2):

That logic looks fine, except you need to close your foreach loop.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) 
{

 if ($count == 3)
 {
 echo '<td>SomeNewText</td>';
 #continue;
 }

 echo $item;
 echo "\n";

 $count++;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean breaking away from the loop when a condition is met, you can do this:

```
<?php
foreach ($items as $item) {
  if ($count == 3) {
    break;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: No, I want to loop thru the whole array, but also I want to be able to add some text somewhere in the middle of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Well not to sure what the problem you want sorted, but there is an error in your code you need to close the foreach loop, which should give you the out come you wanted.

```
echo $item;
echo "\n";

$count++;

} <-- here is missing 

?>
```